# How do I get results to open in new tab

Tags: xslt, google-search-appliance

Link:  http://www.spe.org/search?q=oil&client=onepetro&proxystylesheet=spe&site=SPEsite

We are using GSA as our search engine.  GSA uses XSLT.  When I get a list of results and click on a title, I would like it to open the page in a new tab.  I don't know how to do this and I don't know what code snippet I would include for this.  I'm hoping someone has done this with GSA before.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the newest version of the GSA (6.14), then the searched snippet lies on line 4904-4909 of the DEFAULT NON-TOUCHED XSLT file:

Default:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;a 
      ctype="c"
</xsl:text>
      rank=&quot;<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>&quot;
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>
      href="</xsl:text>
```

Target Blank (Open in new window):

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;a 
      ctype="c"
</xsl:text>
      rank=&quot;<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>
      href="</xsl:text>
```

I hope that helps. You have to do this in every language of the frontend that serves results.